# Как вывести все строки из одной таблицы, которых нету в другой?

Tags: sql, oracle

Идея моего решения, беру первую таблицу и соединяю со второй, где соединениями являются ключи и проверяю их на `null`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 q4
JOIN table2 q ON (q4.Key = q.Key AND q.second_key = q4.second_key)
WHERE q.Key IS NULL and q.second_key is null
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 3):

**Вариант 1:**

```
select *
from t1
where (key1, key2) not in (select key1, key2 from t2)
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
select *
from t1
where not exists(select 1 from t2 where t1.key1=t2.key1 and t1.key2=t2.key2)
```

**Вариант 3:**

```
with ids as (
  select key1, key2 from t1
  minus
  select key1, key2 from t2
)
select t1.* from t1
join ids t2
  on t1.key1=t2.key1 and t1.key2=t2.key2
```

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=867cc550cc7a6bb4acd8227a96010698)